# Turned IMU sensor in robot

Tags: ros2, ros-melodic, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mounted an IMU Sensor not in the default direction but 90 degrees turned.
Does this has an effect on my navigation/ localization/ odometry or can the sensor turn things right due to gravity or something?

-> So my question is: Do I have to turn the IMU_link in my robot description (URDF) and where else?
(I am working with a turtlebot)

Thanks for your advice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367352/turned-imu-sensor-in-robot/) by [lslabon](https://answers.ros.org/users/59110/lslabon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rep 103](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) defines the co-ordinate frames and their orientatioins. If your IMU isn't mounted per this, you will have to correct for it in the urdf file to match the convention (recommended). This is so that your IMU readings can  be compatible with everything ros. Defining the imu_link in your urdf should be enough. Ros/tf will take care of the transforms for you!

Of course you don't have to do it! If you don't care about compatibility (not recommended), you don't need to! You will have to ensure you are applying the correct gravitational forces and that you are reading the correct roll, pitch and yaw in your calculations.

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2020-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2